# Filter pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following pyspark dataframe.

```
# Define the schema for the dataframe
schema = StructType([
    StructField("dt", StringType(), True),
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("value", FloatType(), True)
])

# Create the PySpark dataframe
data = [
    ('2023-04-24 00:00:00', 'A', None),
    ('2023-04-25 00:00:00', 'A', 100.5),
    ('2023-04-24 00:00:00', 'B', None),
    ('2023-04-25 00:00:00', 'B', None),
    ('2023-04-26 00:00:00', 'A', 110.0),
    ('2023-04-26 00:00:00', 'B', None),
    ('2023-04-27 00:00:00', 'A', None),
    ('2023-04-27 00:00:00', 'B', 50.5),
    ('2023-04-28 00:00:00', 'A', 105.0),
    ('2023-04-28 00:00:00', 'B', None),
    ('2023-04-29 00:00:00', 'B', 55.5),
    ('2023-04-29 00:00:00', 'A', 107.0)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df = df.withColumn("dt", col("dt").cast(TimestampType()))
```

For each ID I want to remove all rows before the first row where the `value` column is not null. Below is the expected dataframe:

```
+-------------------+---+-----+
|                 dt| id|value|
+-------------------+---+-----+
|2023-04-25 00:00:00|  A|100.5|
|2023-04-26 00:00:00|  A|110.0|
|2023-04-27 00:00:00|  A| null|
|2023-04-28 00:00:00|  A|105.0|
|2023-04-29 00:00:00|  A|107.0|
|2023-04-27 00:00:00|  B| 50.5|
|2023-04-28 00:00:00|  B| null|
|2023-04-29 00:00:00|  B| 55.5|
+-------------------+---+-----+
```

For simplicity I want to keep the transformations in pyspark, so I cannot convert to other formats (Pandas for instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could create a dummy column that cumulatively adds values as 1 and nulls as 0.

here's an example

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as wd
import sys

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('val_flag', func.col('value').isNotNull().cast('int')). \
    withColumn('val_rn', 
               func.sum('val_flag').over(wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy('dt').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))
               ). \
    filter(func.col('val_rn') != 0). \
    drop('val_flag', 'val_rn'). \
    show()

# +-------------------+---+-----+
# |                 dt| id|value|
# +-------------------+---+-----+
# |2023-04-25 00:00:00|  A|100.5|
# |2023-04-26 00:00:00|  A|110.0|
# |2023-04-27 00:00:00|  A| null|
# |2023-04-28 00:00:00|  A|105.0|
# |2023-04-29 00:00:00|  A|107.0|
# |2023-04-27 00:00:00|  B| 50.5|
# |2023-04-28 00:00:00|  B| null|
# |2023-04-29 00:00:00|  B| 55.5|
# +-------------------+---+-----+
```

---

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('val_flag', func.col('value').isNotNull().cast('int')). \
    withColumn('val_rn', 
               func.sum('val_flag').over(wd.partitionBy('id').orderBy('dt').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))
               ). \
    show()

# +-------------------+---+-----+--------+------+
# |                 dt| id|value|val_flag|val_rn|
# +-------------------+---+-----+--------+------+
# |2023-04-24 00:00:00|  A| null|       0|     0|
# |2023-04-25 00:00:00|  A|100.5|       1|     1|
# |2023-04-26 00:00:00|  A|110.0|       1|     2|
# |2023-04-27 00:00:00|  A| null|       0|     2|
# |2023-04-28 00:00:00|  A|105.0|       1|     3|
# |2023-04-29 00:00:00|  A|107.0|       1|     4|
# |2023-04-24 00:00:00|  B| null|       0|     0|
# |2023-04-25 00:00:00|  B| null|       0|     0|
# |2023-04-26 00:00:00|  B| null|       0|     0|
# |2023-04-27 00:00:00|  B| 50.5|       1|     1|
# |2023-04-28 00:00:00|  B| null|       0|     1|
# |2023-04-29 00:00:00|  B| 55.5|       1|     2|
# +-------------------+---+-----+--------+------+
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked! For others looking, the libraries needed to run the code in this answer are:
`from pyspark.sql import Window as wd` 
and
`from pyspark.sql import functions as func`